# Is absolute bluetooth mouse movements supported in ios?

Tags: ios, node.js, swift

I am trying to send Bluetooth HID Mouse Commands. However the HTML cursor coordinates relative to device screen have no accurate impact on how Screen Cursor (Accessibility Pointer) in IOS Device moves.

For example.

```
Mouse Command: M 0 <X-Axis> <Y-Axis> 00
```

Values we can send (0 - 127 +ve) and (255 = -1, 254 = -2, ... 128 = -127) because bluetooth accepts unsigned integers.

If my HTML Cursor is at (X=20,Y=20), How can I determine what exact value should I send to Bluetooth Screen Cursor (Accessibility Pointer) to go to exact accurate position where HTML Cursor is at.